# Still stuck in update row cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have posted a question and got help but I still dont make it.
Im trying to update a row in cakePHP 2.3.1.I have class Test extend AppModel with $validates array, and the Controller( simplified ) :

```
public function editstudent()   {
if($this->request->data)    {
    $this->Test->stuId= $this->data['Test']['stuId'];
    if ($this->Test->save($this->request->data))    {
        $this->set('state',1);
    }
}
```

My view after edit with suggestion from a user :D :

```
class Test extends AppModel {
var $name= 'Test';
var $primaryKey= 'stuId';
public $validate= array(.......);
}
```

I've set $primaryKey in View,set $this->Test->$primaryKey in controller but still got the error :

> Database Error Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL Query: INSERT INTO cakePhp.tests (stuName, stuDoB, stuAdd) VALUES ('Đào Đức Anh', '2013-03-25', 'Kim Liên')

Can anyone help me out,I really need help,I'm stuck at this for 2 day and cant figure it out :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the following line

```
$this->Test->stuId = $this->data['Test']['stuId'];
```

to

```
$this->Test->id = $this->data['Test']['stuId'];
```

because it is the `id` property that contains the primary key value.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick attempt:**

Try changing `$this->data` to `$this->request->data` in your controller code.

**More things:**

Bottom line, your primary key isn't getting set.

1. Try using (per the CakePHP book) this syntax:

   `public $primaryKey = 'stuId'; //notice "public" instead of "var"`
2. check to find out why 'studId' isn't in the data being saved.

   `debug($this->request->data);`
3. My assumption is, it's not in the request data - if it were, you'd be fine.

> add the studId into the form that's being submitted or
>   get theID into the request data any other way you see fit

**Side note:**

you keep saying "view", but you really mean "model".

Answer (score 0):

Add Your primary key in AppModel.php
public $primaryKey='username';

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.